# How to create an associated object in Sequelize / Node.js ?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

There is 2 models:

```
sequelize.define('Hotel', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    latitude: {
      type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    longitude: {
      type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
      allowNull: false
    },
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    rating: {
      type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    image: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(db) {
        Hotel.hasMany(db.Comment, {
          foreignKey: 'commentable_id',
          scope: {
            commentable: 'hotel'
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

And

```
sequelize.define('Comment', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    content: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false
    },
    commentable: DataTypes.STRING,
    commentable_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  });
```

How can I create associated Comment for existing Hotel instance? For example, I've tried:

```
hotel.addComment(request.models.Comment.create({content: 'content'}))
```

But it doesn't work. Please, tell me, how I can fix it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

request.models.Comment.create() is async, in other words it returns a promise that must be fullfilled before you can use the resolved value to 'feed' the addComment method.

So you should do something like

```
request.models.Comment.create({content: 'content'}).
then(function(comment){
  return hotel.addComment(comment);
});
```